# How to realize a negative voltage with a positive regulated DC output?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, circuit-analysis, batteries, circuit-design

I found an AC adapter that converts 230V 50hz AC to +16V, 0V, 32V (3 pins) DC.  I wanted to convert this into a +12V, -12V dual power supply. Someone suggested that I use a positive buck converter to create the +12V but he told me that I would **not** be able to create a -12V by just using the same technique; a buck for 32V and connect the terminals in reverse for -12V

I didn't get why this is true.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxWZxh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Physically, if I have two 1 V batteries, how should I connect the second battery to get a -1V at *node 2*. Afaik I would just flip the terminals of the second battery like circuit A, but how is this any different from circuit B? Is circuit A even right? Else how would I get a negative voltage with a +1V battery at node 2? In other words, practically, how would I ensure a ground in the middle?

Here's the nameplate of the AC Adapter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAIbo.jpg

Edit: I replaced the transistor with a box with 2 nodes, node 1 requires +1V and node 2 requires -1V

Comment: I don't have a lot of hope that the effort can produce results for you here, but can you open up the adapter and provide us with as much detail as possible about what you find inside?

Comment: @jonk Heres the label https://imgur.com/a/K1VXz8X

Comment: Not with your basic non-isolated buck converter, but you can use any old isolated dc-dc converter to do the job.

Comment: @Hearth ignore the buck for a moment, Is circuit A correct for the intended purpose ?

Comment: @AravindhVasu It's unclear what your intended purpose is. If you just want to have three nodes, with one volt between each adjacent pair, then yes (but if that's how you have your transistor connected, you're just going to fry it!)

Comment: The difference between circuit A and circuit B is that A has that third node, where B just has two (if you ignore the unconnected base of the transistor). Normally, you'd put a ground symbol on that middle node.

Comment: @Hearth Physically how would I do this, given I have 2, 1V batteries how would I put a ground in the middle ?

Comment: Ground where you define 0V, A&B have none.

Comment: Ground is just what you define it to be. If you were building this into a system (and assuming you don't have any problems with ground loops or anything), I would just connect that middle node to the ground plane, which would be connected to earth ground.

Comment: @Hearth Bare with me for a moment. Suppose I have a breadboard. I would connect + of a battery to one rail, negative to the other. Now the voltage across this rail is 1V. For the other battery. I connect its positive to the negative rail and use the negative terminal as a -1V supply. Will this work as a negative supply? Will the potential in that common rail be zero? Thank you for your  patience

Comment: You mention + and - 12 volt the 1and 2 volt. Please make your requirement clearer. What current outputs do you need? | Q3 is the output +16 and +32 relative to a 0 v lead ?

Comment: @AravindhVasu Yes it would work as a negative supply. No the common rail potential won't be zero because it doesn't make *sense* to talk about the potential of a single point. Potential is *always* measured between two points--not as a matter of convention, but because that's literally just how physics works. In geometric terms, you can't talk about the length of a single point, you need to measure the length between two points.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes the output is 16 and 32 with respect to a third lead and I want to make it a +12 V and -12 V supply for my breadboard projects. I'm not sure about the current requirements but they are not beyond the ones specifies in the label

Comment: @Hearth Ahh Alright now I get it, that rail is what we choose as 0. That is the point with which we gauge the other voltages. Okay now, why wouldn't two buck converters with one's terminal reversed not work as a +12V and -12V supply?

Comment: @AravindhVasu That's a bit more detail than I want to go into in the comments section, but it boils down to isolation. If you use two non-isolated converters like that, you'll be shorting one of them out.

Comment: Show the sample schematic of a converter in the question, make a duplicate of it, connect it so that you get +12 V and -12 V. We might be able to show you how the interconnection will short one of the converters. Without a sample Schematic, it is difficult to demonstrate. Your current schematic has ideal floating voltage supplies. Realistic converters usually aren't like that. Make sure your schematic also includes the common power supply from which both converters draw power.

Comment: @AravindhVasu Are you willing to modify your existing AC adapter? My guess is that there is a transformer in there perhaps with a center-tap. (You may be able to tell from the weight.)

Comment: @jonk no its not very heavy. Okay, I'll break in and revert:)

Comment: @AravindhVasu I'm also wondering if this is a "two piece" power supply. Is there a heavy piece that is what plugs into the mains supply, then some power cord going to that pictured "block"?

Comment: **IF** this is in fact a +16V and -16V supply with a common ground (as seems possible and almost likely) then two linear regulators (_12V, -12V) would do what you want with minimal fuss and effort. It should be easy enough to see if the 32-16 = +16V combination can used to produce +12V and the 16-0 combination = -16V can be used to produce -12V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following doesn't answer how to connect your converters to get -12 V.

> I would not be able to create a -12V by just using the same technique; a buck for 32V and connect the terminals in reverse for -12V. I didn't get why this is true.

Confusion arises since you have assumed that the 12 V converters are devices which have only two terminals. They actually have 4 terminals. Two of those terminals (reference or 0V terminals) may be shorted *inside* the converter (left side picture). See the diagram below. If you connect the 12 V of one such converter and 0 V of another together, you are effectively shorting the 12 V and 0 V of the same converter together.

If the input and output of the converter are *isolated* from each other, this type of short doesn't occur (right side picture). A common way the input and output terminals are isolated is via transformers. There is (usually) no electrical connection between the primary side and secondary side; the connection is magnetic.

See the diagram below.

[image: converters with and without isolation]

Comment: After writing this answer, I realise that your proposed connection may be different. However, if you were to draw a similar diagram, i think you could figure out if a short circuit will exist for that configuration or not.